# How to set Preview default saving format as jpg?

Tags: macos, preview

I often take snapshot of screen and paste it to Preview. When I save the image, the default is png. Is there anyway or settings in plist to set the default image format as jpg for saving?

Comment: Not sure this is doable, maybe through AppleScript. You know this, right? http://lifehacker.com/quickly-change-os-xs-default-screenshot-format-and-loc-1489014578

Comment: I would like to do almost the same, except that when I copy part of an image from Preview, and save it, I want the default to change from `.png` (but to `.tiff` not jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that *might* work for you is to change the default screenshot format.

It's covered online in a few places, the earliest reference I found here 
http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/09/screen-capture-in-mac-os-x/

This isn't an answer to the *exact* question you asked.  Saving screenshots to PNG can be a good thing, if you don't want to introduce JPG compression fuzz.  I would prefer to find a solution for changing the default output filetype in Preview, but in the meantime having screenshots save to JPG is adequate.

Posting this in the hope someone else can solve this fully.

Comment: It would be better if you included the details in the link in your answer, as links may break in the future.

Comment: Didn't work for me on High Sierra. The suggested command is: `defaults write com.apple.screencapture type jpeg`

Comment: I also want to change the default save format in Preview, to tiff.